# WebGL2 supported graphic cards

Tags: google-chrome, webgl2

Is there a list of supported/un-supported graphic cards for WebGL2?

I am encountering a problem in two computers, both running Win7 with Chrome 58 (tested on 56 too), with all the WebGL flags enabled, one computer has nvidia quadro 600 and the other ati radeon HD 2400, both with latest drivers and I get an error that the browser doesn't support WebGL2.
I used the khronos' conformance test at: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/webgl-conformance-tests.html?version=2.0.1

Anyone encountered a similar problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

FIRST my Reputation is to low i cant post more then 2 links. Don't worry we find a way around Copy+Paste the text/that/might/look/like/a/link

Type 
chrome://gpu/

into the adressbar and you see how good Chrome communicate with the Graphiccard and what task it can perform.  - here are some switches to enable and tweak your default(if blacklisted) configuration:

peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Take into account
superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser

Also on Windows OpenGL/WebGL content has to transpile through so called ANGLE interface into DIRECTX. Probably the bug occurs on side of DirectX. Your GraphicCard was listed in ANGLE only for DirectX Version 10. and WebGL 1.0 You can bypass and start using native OpenGL by using the switch

--enable-unsafe-es3-apis

Try Chrome from a Dev channel/Canary. 
the problem may fixed in an upcoming stable Version of Chrome

chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel